# Definition of a convergent sequence in a metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

The definition of convergence of a sequence in a metric space that I've been given is as follows:

A sequence $(x_n)_{n>0}$ in some metric space X is convergent if

$\exists a\in X$ $\forall\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N>0$  n>N $\implies$ $d(x_n,a)<\varepsilon$

My question is: Why does $a$ necessarily have to be an element of X?

For example, taking $X = (0,1)$ and $x_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ surely gives a convergent sequence?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your sequence converge to?

Comment: 0, which isn't an element of X. I understand that this isn't allowed and hence $x_n$ is deemed to not be convergent, but *why* is convergence defined like this? It seems counterintuitive

Comment: Your essentially embedding your space in another space where the convergence is standard. But the limit would depend on which space you embed into, so the definition might not be well defined.

Comment: At least that's why I think the limit has to be in the space.

Answer (score 1):

This becomes relevant when we discuss completeness of a metric space.
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. We say that $(X, d)$ is complete if every Cauchy-sequence is convergent. Obviously, $(X, d_E)$ is not complete if $X = \mathbb{Q}$ and $d_E$ is the euclidian metric. Just consider the sequence
$$
q_n := \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n
$$
that is obviously a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$. By your definition it does *not* converge because its $d_E$-limit in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\exp(1) \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and limits are unique. This does also mean that $q_n$ is Cauchy in $(\mathbb{Q}, d_E)$.

Sometimes, it really makes a difference to define metric spaces that are subsets of larger, known metric spaces. For example: Is $\mathbb{Q}$ an open set in $(\mathbb{Q}, d_E)$? Is $\mathbb{Q}$ open in $(\mathbb{R}, d_E)$?

And by the way: How else would you define the limit, if not as a point in $X$? How do you even know what happens outside of $X$?